# Substract Two Dataframes by Index and Keep String Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to subtract two data frames by indexes:

```
# importing pandas as pd
import pandas as pd

# Creating the second dataframe
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Type":['T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'T4', 'T5'],
                    "A":[10, 11, 7, 8, 5],
                    "B":[21, 5, 32, 4, 6],
                    "C":[11, 21, 23, 7, 9],
                    "D":[1, 5, 3, 8, 6]},
                    index =["2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005"])
df1
 
# Creating the first dataframe
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1, 2, 2, 2],
                    "B":[3, 2, 4, 3],
                    "C":[2, 2, 7, 3],
                    "D":[1, 3, 2, 1]},
                    index =["2000", "2002", "2003", "2004"])
df2

# Desired
df = pd.DataFrame({"Type":['T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'T4', 'T5'],
                    "A":[10, 9, 5, 6, 5],
                    "B":[21, 3, 28, 1, 6],
                    "C":[11, 19, 16, 4, 9],
                    "D":[1, 2, 1, 7, 5]},
                    index =["2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005"])
df

df1.subtract(df2)
```

However, it returns in some cases NAs, I would like to keep values from the first df1 if not deductable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could handle NaN using:

```
df1.subtract(df2).combine_first(df1).dropna(how='all')
```

output:

```
         A     B     C    D Type
2001  10.0  21.0  11.0  1.0   T1
2002   9.0   3.0  19.0  2.0   T2
2003   5.0  28.0  16.0  1.0   T3
2004   6.0   1.0   4.0  7.0   T4
2005   5.0   6.0   9.0  6.0   T5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `select_dtypes` to choose the correct data type, then subtract the `reindex` data:

```
(df1.select_dtypes(include='number')
    .sub(df2.reindex(df1.index, fill_value=0))
    .join(df1.select_dtypes(exclude='number'))
)
```

Output:

```
       A   B   C  D Type
2001  10  21  11  1   T1
2002   9   3  19  2   T2
2003   5  28  16  1   T3
2004   6   1   4  7   T4
2005   5   6   9  6   T5
```